# How to find the RGB value of excel's theme colors?

Tags: excel, colors, themes, rgb

In Excel, when you try and change the font color, you are presented with these 4 options: an "Automatic" button, a "Theme Colors" section, a "Standard Colors" section and a "More Colors" button.

I would like to find out the RGB values of the Theme Colors, and to be more specific: the "White, Background 1, Darker 15%" option.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an article that helped: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/microsoft-office-standard-colors-magic-rgb-codes-david-gray

As for the "White, Background 1, Darker 15%" color: it ended up being "#D9D9D9"...

Answer (score 0):

### Start macro recorder, apply desired cell style

You can use Excel "Record macro" feature.
After you start it, apply the desired cell style.
Stop recording.
See the cell properties that were applied.